How to patch user attributes using microsoft-graph-beta in Java
I use below beta Java SDK.
<artifactId>microsoft-graph-beta</artifactId>
<version>6.4.0</version>

I want to update existing attributes(identity here).
        GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(_clientSecretCredential,
                    new String[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" });

        ...

        String filter = String.format("identities/any(c:c/issuer eq '%s' and c/issuerAssignedId eq '%s')", issuer, issuerAssignedId); 
        
        User user = graphClient
                .users()
                .get(requestConfig -> {
                    requestConfig.queryParameters.filter = filter;
                })
                .getValue().get(0);

        for (ObjectIdentity identity: user.getIdentities()) {

            if(identity.getIssuerAssignedId().equalsIgnoreCase(issuerAssignedId)){
        
                System.out.println("original issuerAssignedId = " + issuerAssignedId + " new issuerAssignedId = " + newIssuerAssignedId);
                identity.setIssuerAssignedId(newIssuerAssignedId);
            }
        }

But I don't see any patch() method in  UsersRequestBuilder.java. How can I patch user?

Found the API document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java#request-1
    User updateUser = new User();
    updateUser.setSurname("NewLastName");
    updateUser.setIdentities(user.getIdentities());

    User result = graphClient.users().byUserId(user.getId()).patch(updateUser);

It needs new version.
microsoft-graph-beta
6.13.0
